# What is the registrations per second throughput for Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-notificationhub

Does anyone know what is the registrations per second throughput for Azure Notification Hub?

I ran a background task to sync NH with our user database however it started to recieve timeouts from notifcation hub - presumably some throttling.

We found that we could process around 18,000 registrations per hour (300/second) without any issue. The peak hour in the graph when it failed shows 44,000 registrations in that hour.

Answer (score 0):

I work on Windows Azure Notification Hubs. The one you report above is indeed the max throughput that we allow on our system for registration operations.
We are working on a batching API that will improve this dramatically.

Please note that registration operations (while being free) are currently capped (to prevent abuse) at 4 times the number of pushes you are buying in your unit (e.g. if you have 1 standard unit you get ~165k pushes/day and ~165k*4 registration operations per day).